# Neo4j match nodes that are in relationship with one OR another node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to wrap my head around one query. For example I have this pattern `(photo:Photo)-[:AUTHOR]->(user:User)`. User can have friends `(user:User)-[:FRIEND]->(friend:User)`. So how can i make a query in which i will find all `:Photo`s made by me or my friends and sort them by date if there is any?

```
MATCH (user:User {id: 'me'}), (user)-[:FRIEND]-(friend:User)
//other pattern matches that I need to do
OPTIONAL MATCH (photo:Photo)-[:AUTHOR]-(user | friend)
RETURN photo
ORDER BY photo.date
LIMIT 42
```

But as far as I know this costruct `(user | friend)` is invalid. So what's correct way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only look for a single relationship to a defined `User` node, a simple way would be to use a variable length relationship with length 0 to 1. This collects all nodes with a distance of 0 (which is you start node) and all nodes with a distance of 1.

```
MATCH (user:User {id: 'me'})-[:FRIEND*0..1]-(me_and_friend:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (photo:Photo)-[:AUTHOR]-(me_and_friend)
RETURN photo
ORDER BY photo.date
LIMIT 42
```

A more generic solution would be to `collect` different nodes into arrays, combine these arrays and then use `UNWIND` to `MATCH` again:

```
MATCH (user:User {id: 'me'}), (user)-[:FRIEND]-(friend:User)
WITH collect(user)+collect(friend) AS me_and_friends
UNWIND me_and_friends AS allusers
OPTIONAL MATCH (photo:Photo)-[:AUTHOR]-(allusers)
RETURN photo
ORDER BY photo.date
LIMIT 42
```

This could be useful if you `MATCH` longer paths or more complex patterns.

Comment: Wow, i should have thought about using unwind in this way myself. Never used variable length, and thats interesting that you can use 0 length to 'refer' node to itself, awesome snippets, thanks!
In case someone else will want to post some handy solution, i will wait some time before accepting answer.

Comment: oops, sorry, forgot about this question, accepted! Thanks!